# Implementing LLL algorithm as been said on Wikipedia, but getting into serious issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, cryptography, ecmascript-6

I am not sure my issue is related to programming or related to concept of LLL algorithm and what has been mentioned on Wikipedia.

I decided to implement LLL algorithm as it has been written on [**Wikipedia** (step-by-step / line-by-line)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm#LLL_Algorithm) to actually learn the algorithm and make sure it is truly working but I am getting unexpected or invalid results.

So, I used JavaScript (programming language) and node.js (JavaScript engine) to implement it and [**this is the git repository**](https://github.com/amir734jj/JavaScript_EMC6_linear_algebra_tools) to get the complete code.

Long story short, value of K gets out of range, for example when we have only 3 vectors (array size is 3, thus maximum value of index would be 2), but k becomes 3 and it is nonsense.

My code is step-by-step (line-by-line) implementation of the algorithm mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm#LLL_Algorithm) and what I did was only implementing it. So I don't what is the issue.

```
// ** important
//  {b} set of vectors are denoted by this.matrix_before
//  {b*} set of vectors are denoted by this.matrix_after
calculate_LLL() {
    this.matrix_after = new gs(this.matrix_before, false).matrix; // initialize after vectors: perform Gram-Schmidt, but do not normalize
    var flag = false; // invariant
    var k = 1;

    while (k <= this.dimensions && !flag) {
        for (var j = k - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (Math.abs(this.mu(k, j)) > 0.5) {
                var to_subtract = tools.multiply(Math.round(this.mu(k, j)), this.matrix_before[j], this.dimensions);
                this.matrix_before[k] = tools.subtract(this.matrix_before[k], to_subtract, this.dimensions);

                this.matrix_after = new gs(this.matrix_before, false).matrix; // update after vectors: perform Gram-Schmidt, but do not normalize
            }
        }

        if (tools.dot_product(this.matrix_after[k], this.matrix_after[k], this.dimensions) >= (this.delta - Math.pow(this.mu(k, k - 1), 2)) * tools.dot_product(this.matrix_after[k - 1], this.matrix_after[k - 1], this.dimensions)) {
            if (k + 1 >= this.dimensions) { // invariant: there is some issue, something is wrong
                flag = true; // invariant is broken
                console.log("something bad happened ! (1)");
            }

            k++;
            // console.log("if; k, j");
            // console.log(k + ", " + j);
        } else {
            var temp_matrix = this.matrix_before[k];
            this.matrix_before[k] = this.matrix_before[k - 1];
            this.matrix_before[k - 1] = temp_matrix;

            this.matrix_after = new gs(this.matrix_before, false).matrix; // update after vectors: perform Gram-Schmidt, but do not normalize

            if (k === Math.max(k - 1, 1) || k >= this.dimensions || Math.max(k - 1, 1) >= this.dimensions) { // invariant: there is some issue, something is wrong
                flag = true; // invariant is broken
                console.log("something bad happened ! (2)");
            }
            k = Math.max(k - 1, 1);

            // console.log("else; k, j");
            // console.log(k + ", " + j);
        }

        console.log(this.matrix_before);
        console.log("\n");

    } // I added this flag variable to prevent getting exceptions and terminate the loop gracefully

    console.log("final: ");
    console.log(this.matrix_before);
}

// calculated mu as been  mentioned on Wikipedia
// mu(i, j) = <b_i, b*_j> / <b*_j, b*_j>
mu(i, j) {
    var top = tools.dot_product(this.matrix_before[i], this.matrix_after[j], this.dimensions);
    var bottom = tools.dot_product(this.matrix_after[j], this.matrix_after[j], this.dimensions);

    return top / bottom;
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the algorithm that is on Wikipedia:

[image]

---

**Update #1**: I added more comments to the code to clarify the question hoping that someone would help.

Just in case you are wondering about the already available implementation of the code, you can type: [`LatticeReduce[{{0,1},{2,0}}]` wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LatticeReduce%5B%7B%7B0,1%7D,%7B2,0%7D%7D%5D) to see how this code suppose to behave.

**Update #2**: I cleaned up the code more and added a validate function to make Gram Schmidt code is working correctly, but still code fails and value of k exceeds number of dimensions (or number of vectors) which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Found this implementation. Maybe it will help. https://github.com/indutny/lll-reduction/blob/master/lib/lll.js

Comment: I wonder why no one has answered my question. It is a straightforward implementation of Wikipedia algorithm.

Comment: In the notation of the Wikipedia page, is `this.dimensions` intended to be *n* (max index) or *n*+1 (number of vectors)?

Comment: I don't know but this.dimension in my code is: n

Comment: I ask because e.g. if `this.dimensions` is *n* then it's perfectly OK for k+1 to equal `this.dimensions` before *k* gets incremented -- the value of *k* will then still be a valid index.

Comment: Separate question: just going by the name, `this.dimensions` sounds like it should mean something more like *m* (the dimension of the space the vectors live in) than *n* (the number of vectors minus 1), doesn't it?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Regrading question #1) k+1 = this.dimension code throws exception (try it yourself, download git repository and comment out flag = true from the code). Regrading question #2) LLL algorithm reduces a lattice. lattice can be represented by a N x M matrix and N and M can be different. In this code I assumed N and M are the same (and equal to this.dimension).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Thank you so much for checking out my question. After 200+ views and 8 up votes you are the first one that might be actually interested.

Comment: If k+1=`this.dimensions` makes it throw an exception then I don't think it can be true that `this.dimensions`=n, because we're meant to have vectors indexed by 0..n and asking for the nth of those shouldn't throw.

Comment: OK, so the code on GitHub says `this.dimensions = matrix[0].length` which looks to me as if it's n+1 rather than n, if your vectors are numbered 0..n -- no?

Comment: I just changed while to: while (k < this.dimensions && !flag) and code returns correct result. It works! no exception! Let me test the code with more test cases. Thank you.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan YOU ARE GENIUS!

Comment: OK. I'll make that into an answer and you can accept it if you feel so inclined.

Comment: I was following this post from start and can't help not to think that changing the `while (k < this.dimensions && !flag)` was the only that fixed this issue? If you try that on the original code that was posted with this question, one still gets an issue so what "else" changed significantly that made it work. Just curious I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm description in Wikipedia uses rather odd notation -- the vectors are numbered 0..n (rather than, say, 0..n-1 or 1..n), so the total number of vectors is n+1.

The code you've posted here treats `this.dimensions` as if it corresponds to n in the Wikipedia description. Nothing wrong with that so far.

However, the constructor in the full source file on GitHub sets `this.dimensions = matrix[0].length`. Two things about this look wrong. The first is that surely `matrix[0].length` is more like *m* (the dimension of the space) than *n* (the number of vectors, minus 1 for unclear reasons). The second is that if it's meant to be *n* then you need to subtract 1 because the number of vectors is n+1, not n.

So if you want to use `this.dimensions` to mean n, I think you need to initialize it as `matrix.length-1`. With the square matrix in your test case, using `matrix[0].length-1` would work, but I think the code will then break when you feed in a non-square matrix. The name `dimensions` is kinda misleading, too; maybe just `n` to match the Wikipedia description?

Or you could call it something like `nVectors`, let it equal `matrix.length`, and change the rest of the code appropriately, which just means an adjustment in the termination condition for the main loop.